# Will upgrading Managed Package fail Test classes in the package?

Tags: unit-test, managed-package, upgrade

We have a Managed Package already installed in the client's system (version 1) they have created an automation that creates xxy__Project__c records.
In the managed package, we have a test class that asserts on listOfProjects.size() == 10.

When we upgrade the package (version 1.1) will the test class fail and will that block the package to upgrade?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it will not fail, because they will not run.

when the package is installing or upgrading, no tests are performed on subscriber org.
Tests of the managed package are only executing when you are creating a package.